# not able to format hibernate resultset into proper json

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I am running into issue related to conversion of Hibernate resultset into JSON using Jackson. I am fetching records from database using below statement.

```
List<IndoorRegister> indoorRegister = entityManager.createQuery("select indoorId, srnoPart1, srnoPart2, dateOfAdmit, dateOfDischarge, patientName, address, age, diagnosis, treatment, fees, remarks, createDate, modifyDate from IndoorRegister").getResultList()
```

After that, I am converting list into json using below lines

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<IndoorRegister> allIndoorEntries = indoorRegisterService.getIndoorRegister();
String jsonForm = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(allIndoorEntries)
```

However string form of JSON returns something like -

```
[[ 1, "03122014", "01", 1417545000000, 1417977000000, "test", "sdfg", 20, "Diagnosis - 3", "MTP", 12.23, "sdg", 1418110332000, 1418110332000 ], [ 2, "09122014", "01", 1418063400000, 1418754600000, "test", "test", 18, "Diagnosis - 3", "Tubectomy", 12.23, "sf", 1419486569000, 1419486569000 ], [ 3, "09122014", "2", 1418063400000, 1418668200000, "sfsafd", "asdfsa", 19, "Diagnosis - 3", "MTP", 12.32, "sadf", 1419527458000, 1419527458000 ], [ 4, "10122014", "1", 1418149800000, 1418668200000, "sfsafd", "asdfsa", 19, "Diagnosis - 3", "MTP", 12.32, "sadf", 1419527509000, 1419527509000 ]]
```

My requirement is to return the json containing string and value as -

```
[{"indoorId":1,"srnoPart1":"12262014","srnoPart2":"01","dateOfAdmit":1419655160683,"dateOfDischarge":1419655160683,"patientName":"abc","address":"any add","age":16,"diagnosis":"diagnosis","treatment":null,"fees":12.23,"remarks":"test","createDate":1419655160683,"modifyDate":1419655160683}, {"indoorId":2,"srnoPart1":"12262014","srnoPart2":"02","dateOfAdmit":1419655160683,"dateOfDischarge":1419655160683,"patientName":"abc","address":"any add","age":16,"diagnosis":"diagnosis","treatment":null,"fees":12.23,"remarks":"test","createDate":1419655160683,"modifyDate":1419655160683}]
```

My IndoorRegister.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "INDOOR_REGISTER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class IndoorRegister {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "INDOOR_ID")
    int indoorId;

    @Column(name = "SRNO_PART1")
    String srnoPart1;

    @Column(name = "SRNO_PART2")
    String srnoPart2;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_ADMIT")
    Date dateOfAdmit;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_DISCHARGE")
    Date dateOfDischarge;

    @Column(name = "PATIENT_NAME")
    String patientName;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    String address;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    int age;

    @Column(name = "DIAGNOSIS")
    String diagnosis;

    @Column(name = "TREATMENT")
    String treatment;

    @Column(name = "FEES")
    double fees;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "REMARKS")
    String remarks;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
    Date createDate;

    @Column(name = "MODIFY_DATE")
    Date modifyDate;

    /**
     * @return the indoorId
     */
    public int getIndoorId() {
        return indoorId;
    }

    /**
     * @param indoorId the indoorId to set
     */
    public void setIndoorId(int indoorId) {
        this.indoorId = indoorId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the srnoPart1
     */
    public String getSrnoPart1() {
        return srnoPart1;
    }

    /**
     * @param srnoPart1 the srnoPart1 to set
     */
    public void setSrnoPart1(String srnoPart1) {
        this.srnoPart1 = srnoPart1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the srnoPart2
     */
    public String getSrnoPart2() {
        return srnoPart2;
    }

    /**
     * @param srnoPart2 the srnoPart2 to set
     */
    public void setSrnoPart2(String srnoPart2) {
        this.srnoPart2 = srnoPart2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dateOfAdmit
     */
    public Date getDateOfAdmit() {
        return dateOfAdmit;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateOfAdmit the dateOfAdmit to set
     */
    public void setDateOfAdmit(Date dateOfAdmit) {
        this.dateOfAdmit = dateOfAdmit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dateOfDischarge
     */
    public Date getDateOfDischarge() {
        return dateOfDischarge;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateOfDischarge the dateOfDischarge to set
     */
    public void setDateOfDischarge(Date dateOfDischarge) {
        this.dateOfDischarge = dateOfDischarge;
    }

    /**
     * @return the patientName
     */
    public String getPatientName() {
        return patientName;
    }

    /**
     * @param patientName the patientName to set
     */
    public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
        this.patientName = patientName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * @param address the address to set
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * @return the diagnosis
     */
    public String getDiagnosis() {
        return diagnosis;
    }

    /**
     * @param diagnosis the diagnosis to set
     */
    public void setDiagnosis(String diagnosis) {
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    }

    /**
     * @return the treatment
     */
    public String getTreatment() {
        return treatment;
    }

    /**
     * @param treatment the treatment to set
     */
    public void setTreatment(String treatment) {
        this.treatment = treatment;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fees
     */
    public double getFees() {
        return fees;
    }

    /**
     * @param fees the fees to set
     */
    public void setFees(double fees) {
        this.fees = fees;
    }

    /**
     * @return the remarks
     */
    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    /**
     * @param remarks the remarks to set
     */
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    /**
     * @return the createDate
     */
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param createDate the createDate to set
     */
    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modifyDate
     */
    public Date getModifyDate() {
        return modifyDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param modifyDate the modifyDate to set
     */
    public void setModifyDate(Date modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }


}
```

Any help or pointer would be really great.

Comment: Can you post contents of `IndoorRegister`

Comment: Hi Darshan, I have added the contents of IndoorRegister

Comment: Which versions of Hibernate and Jackson are you using? I've tested with Hibernate 4.3.7 and Jackson 2.2.3, and results are indeed serializing as you want (with field names)

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.0.1 and Jackson 1.9.13 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson). I did not find 2.2.3 version of jackson. Can you please point me to the URL.

Comment: Here you are, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.4 it seems they changed the artifact's group. Also, you may need more artifacts, like jackson-annotations and jackson-databind.

Comment: Well now I'm absolutely confused, I've tested with Hibernate 4.0.1 and Jackson 1.9.13 (in JBoss 7.1.1) and also works. Maybe you'll want to isolate the problem a bit, for example you could instance and fill manually an `IndoorRegister` object and serilizing it to see the results.

Comment: Thanks for trying out. I am also thinking of the same. Let me try and get back.